# What purpose does `FirstOrDefault()` have in a nested NEST `Term()` Query?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST to query an ElasticSearch index using a nested query and have everything working, but was confused as to the purpose of one line of code in the query. Before I go any further I'll provide all the objects and the query itself.

Here's the object that maps to the index `"country"`.

```
  [ElasticsearchType(Name = "country")]
  public class CountrySearchDto : ISearchIndex {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IsoCode {get; set;}
    public string CountryCode{get; set;}
    [Nested]
    public List<AreaSearchDto> Areas {get; set;}

  }
}
```

Here's the object that maps to the index `"area"`.

```
public class AreaSearchDto : ISearchIndex{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GuideUrl { get; set; }    
  }
```

As you can see, the `country` index has `areas` nested inside of it. The query I've made is used for searching Countries by the areas that are nested inside.

Here's the query.

```
    var searchResults = await _searchClient.SearchAsync<CountrySearchDto>(s => s
        .Index("country")
        .Query(q => q
            .Nested(c => c
                .Path(p => p.Areas)
                .Query(nq => nq
                    .Term(t => t.Areas.FirstOrDefault().Name, searchTerm) // Where searchTerm is a string like "Sydney" or "London"
            ))
        )
    );
```

I understand how the Nested query is working, and it's getting all the information that I need correctly. But what is this line of code doing?

```
.Term(t => t.Areas.FirstOrDefault().Name, searchTerm) // Where searchTerm is a string like "Sydney" or "London"
```

Wouldn't the `FirstOrDefault()` restrict the query to only match on the first Areas value, rather than all of them? Obviously that isn't the case, but I'm wondering if anyone could explain what's going on here.

Comment: t.Areas is an array of Areas but you need to provide a Areas object in this lambda, so this is used to access an Areas object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t => t.Areas.FirstOrDefault().Name` is a lambda expression that will resolve to a field name to use within the Elasticsearch query. It is not *executed* per se, to retrieve the value of the first area name, but rather traversed to build up a string for the name of the field that the term query targets. As aHochstein points out in the comments, the target for the term query inside the nested query is a field of `AreaSearchDto` as a path from the root of the document represented by the `CountrySearchDto` type that the search query is scoped to. Using a lambda expression to perform this traversal allows you to take advantage of types.

With a `searchTerm` of `"searchTerm"`, the query generated is

```
POST http://localhost:9200/country/country/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "areas",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "areas.name": {
            "value": "searchTerm"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The lambda expression has been evaluated to the string `"areas.name"`